# Graph Theory Vertex Problem

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph of order $8$ with $V(G)=\{v_1, v_2,...,v_8\}$ such that deg $v_i=i$ for $1 \leq i \leq 7$. What is deg $v_8$.

Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a fun question, I knew as a riddle about people shaking hands.

I'll give you the start:

- $v_7$ has degree $7$, so it is connected to everybody else (including $v_8$).
- this means $v_1$ is connected only to $v_7$.
- so $v_6$ is connected to everybody except $v_1$ (this includes $v_8$).
- ...

Answer (score 4):

You must join $v_7$ with all other vertices.
After that, $v_1$ is already "fed up". What can you now say about $v_6$? What happens then to $v_2$? And so on.